# Is there any relation between Minimal polynomial of a matrix in M(n,C) and its diagonalizablity?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Is there any relation between Minimal polynomial of a matrix in $M(n,\mathbb C)$ and its diagonalizablity? I want to mean looking at the roots of minimal or characteristic polynomial can we say about its diagonalizablity?

Answer (score 2):

A matrix $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb C)$ is diagonizable iff all roots of is minimal polynomial are simple.

Comment: can you give me a link for the proof?

Comment: Any decent linear algebra book, @user121418 . The min. pol.'s roots are simple iff it is a product of different linear pol's iff the maximal size for a Jordan block of each and all the eigenvalues is $\;1\;$ iff the matrix's diagonalizable.